# Visual studio deployment setup: Process not getting killed

Tags: forms, visual-c++, setup-deployment

I have created a form application in VC++ and developed a deployment setup.
We I run the sources through visual studio, the form pops up. When I close it however, it doesnot exit completely. The task manager still shows the process running. So need to kill explicitly from taskmanager. 
I wrote a kill application snippet in the form's destructor. After running it through visual studio, the task manager shows that the process is killed and works as expected.

Now when I created the deployment setup with the same sources, it does not work well. The task manager still shows the process running even after closing the form.

I would really appreciate if someone helps me out!

Thanks in advance,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I close it however, it doesnot exit completely.

This looks like a problem in your application code.

> So need to kill explicitly from taskmanager. I wrote a kill
>   application snippet in the form's destructor.

That's a bad idea. Your application should close gracefully. You shouldn't have to kill its process.

Comment: This is because my app was dependent upon other process<not visible on task manager ?! though> which i need to stop before closing the the app. So I wrote a process close command in form's destructor. And that worked fine. Now everything is working well.